# using hashCode to return huge Integer ids for HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

`HashMap` works with fixed length arrays internally and indexes where values will are stored are based on hash of the `key`, and in case of collion for hash it will make a linked list on that index and then will use `equals` method to return the correct value while reading.

I have a custom class which has got an `Integer` id as a sequential number, I used this class as `'key'` of the HashSet and in `hasCode()` method I am return the id, which means that the underlying array of `HashSet` will look for index number N that I return from `hasCode()` to store the value.

Now, even if I return `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1` from the `hashCode()` the `HashMap` is able to store the value in the map. The question is, is `Integer.MAX_VALUE -1` being used as index of underlying array? If yes, does the `HashMap` create that huge array when we create its instance?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not the case. Hashmap would allocate an array of 16 elements initially and then resize depending on the loading factor. So in the case of hash code returning an integer that won't fit in that array or even a negative number, there is a simple mechanism that could be used like absolute value of the mod. In a simplified form:

```
 int arrayIndex = abs(hashCode) % arraySize;
```

Comment: Sorry, that 'could be' indicates pure speculation here. Hash tables dont work that way.

Comment: Actually, that is a simplified but otherwise accurate description of exactly how `HashMap` works, per the official docs and source, @Gyro Gearless. No speculation needed.